# Pandemic - Can an action be performed by different players during action phase?

Tags: pandemic, pandemic-legacy-season-1

In *Pandemic*, can an action be performed by different players during action phase, by using *Funded Event* cards?
For example:
"*Flexible Aid Package*" allows a. player to perform 1-3 extra actions (by discarding cards).
Can this card be used by "player #2" while "player #1" is in the "*action phase*"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Flexible Aid Package specifically says that "the current player" takes 1 additional action per card you discard.

So if player 2 uses Flexible Aid Package during player 1's turn, player 2 will discard 1-3 cards from their hand, and that will give player 1 extra actions. Player 2 cannot take the extra actions.

Same with the Borrowed Time event; it only gives the "current player" (the player who is taking their turn" the extra action.